# Smokeping FTPtransfer probe

Tags: ftp, ping, network-monitoring

I'm trying to set up a SmokePing FTPtransfer graph but with no luck.
I have the ping graphs all figured out but the FTP graph is just empty.
Here is my Probes config:

```
*** Probes ***

+ FPing

binary = /usr/bin/fping

+ FTPtransfer
destfile = /home/bunny/speed.speed
forks = 1
min_interval = 1
mode = get
offset = 50%
srcfile = ftp.sunet.se/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/ISO-IMAGES/8.3/FreeBSD-8.3-RELEASE-i386-bootonly.iso
step = 60
timeout = 180 # mandatory
```

And here is the Target config:

```
*** Targets ***

probe = FPing

+ FTP
probe = FTPtransfer
menu = FTP
title = FTP 52MB file from ftp.sunet.se
host = ftp.sunet.se
localaddr = myhost-nat-if
username = user
password = password
pings = 5
```

The graph is showing on my page but does not get filled with the time to complete the transfer.
The FTP-server does not require any password or username, tho I've tried with user:password and that works fine.

If anyone got this Probe set up and working I would love to take a look at your Probes and Targets config.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using passive mode?
Set passive mode with:

```
passive = yes
```

My next challange is figuring out/configuring where smokeping stores the retrieved files.
Seems to me like it is not saved in the data directory but wherever you start smokeping from.

Comment: FTP file storage solved by using "destfile" directive